# random python mask array with some rule: no two (or not too much) adjacent false values

Tags: python, random, mask

I want to mask part of the words in the text

```
['First', 'Citizen:', 'Before', 'we', 'proceed', 'any', 'further,', 'hear', 'me', 'speak.', 'All:', 'Speak,', 'speak.', 'First', 'Citizen:', 'You', 'are', 'all', 'resolved', 'rather', 'to', 'die', 'than', 'to', 'famish?', 'All:', 'Resolved.', 'resolved.', 'First', 'Citizen:', 'First,', 'you', 'know', 'Caius', 'Marcius', 'is', 'chief', 'enemy', 'to', 'the', 'people.']
```

using a Python mask. I implement a random Python mask

```
mask = np.ones(LEN, dtype=int)
maskrate=0.2 # percentage of masked words <1
nbmask=int(np.floor(LEN*maskrate))
mask[-nbmask:] = 0
np.random.shuffle(mask)
mask = mask.astype(bool)
print (mask )

masked_words=[]

for a,b in zip(words, mask):
    print (a)
    if b:
        masked_words.append(a)
    else:
        masked_words.append('_')
```

However I would like to avoid that too many words in a row are masked. If numerically possible, no two contiguous words should be masked. Such as what is happening here

```
_ Citizen: _ we proceed _ further, _ me speak. All: _ speak. First Citizen: You are all resolved rather to die than _ _ All: _ resolved. First Citizen: First, you know Caius Marcius is chief enemy to the people.
```

I would like randomness to be slightly more evenly distributed ...

Comment: since creating the mask all at once is not... predictable you can try to create the mask recursively, at least you you could control the adjacency of masked words

Answer (score 1):

To have more control on the randomness of the values in the mask I use pure Python, numpy is not so flexible, usually. A recursive approach is recommended.

```
import random 

def gen_mask(n_w, mask_rate=.2):
    if mask_rate >= .5: raise Exception('mask rate always smaller than .5, thanks.')

    n_o = int(n_w * mask_rate)  # amount of words to be shaded words
    o_indexes = []
    while True:
        if len(o_indexes) == n_o:
            break
        r = random.randrange(0, n_w - 1)

        if r not in o_indexes:
            # adjacency condition
            if not r - 1 in o_indexes and not r + 1 in o_indexes:
                o_indexes += [r]
                o_indeces.sort()

    mask = [False] * n_w
    for o in o_indexes:
        mask[o] = True
    return mask


words = ['First', 'Citizen:', 'Before', 'we', 'proceed', 'any', 'further,', 'hear', 'me', 'speak.', 'All:', 'Speak,', 'speak.', 'First', 'Citizen:', 'You', 'are', 'all', 'resolved', 'rather', 'to', 'die', 'than', 'to', 'famish?', 'All:', 'Resolved.', 'resolved.', 'First', 'Citizen:', 'First,', 'you', 'know', 'Caius', 'Marcius', 'is', 'chief', 'enemy', 'to', 'the', 'people.']

n_w = len(words)
m_rate = .2
n_o = int(n_w*m_rate)

for i in range(2, 5):
    random.seed(10**i)
    mask = gen_mask(n_w, mask_rate=.2)
    print(' '.join(['_' if m else w for w, m in zip(words, mask)]))
```

Output

```
First Citizen: Before we proceed any further, _ me _ All: _ speak. First Citizen: You are all resolved rather to die _ to famish? _ Resolved. _ First _ First, you _ Caius Marcius is chief enemy to the people.
First Citizen: Before we _ any _ hear me speak. _ Speak, speak. First Citizen: You are all resolved rather to die _ to famish? _ Resolved. _ First _ First, you know Caius _ is chief enemy to the people.
_ Citizen: _ we proceed any further, _ me speak. All: _ speak. First Citizen: You _ all resolved _ to die than to famish? All: Resolved. resolved. First Citizen: First, you _ Caius Marcius is _ enemy to the people.
```

**Remark**  It is clear that the `mask_rate` should never be equal or greater than 0.5 (due to the adjacency condition). If equal to 0.5 it just an "alternating" mask

Comment: Thanks, however this does not really controls or observes the %True: if bad luck there might be a lot more blanks than expected...

Comment: the amount of blanks depends on the amount of words and on the mask_rate. By keeping these parameter fix then the mask generated will have always a constant amount of blanks but in different positions and never adjacent. Did I miss smt in the question or do you have an example where it fails?